# What is mc parameter in StackExchange Redis log?

Tags: logging, caching, stackexchange.redis

I used StackExchange.Redis 2.6.48 for caching. It works well during rush hours and normal hours. But sometimes it crashes **RANDOMLY** during the hours when the system load is low!
Here is a sample log I have in a non traffic time at 6am:

> Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=24KiB, 5112ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=HMGET, next: HMGET DeviceCapabilities::xxx, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 143248, serverEndpoint: something, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: something(SE.Redis-v2.6.48.48654), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=1,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=2,QueuedItems=1757,CompletedItems=382420032), v: 2.6.48.48654 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

I am trying to understand the reason for this error. In the example above, one of the parameters is *mc*, which I do not understand. Any suggestions for *mc* parameter OR any suggestions to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. Found this in source code

```
Add(data, sb, "Multiplexer-Connects", "mc", $"{multiplexer._connectAttemptCount}/{multiplexer._connectCompletedCount}/{multiplexer._connectionCloseCount}");
```

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/02c29ef8e8ddf8de9556c113a8a6fb1563f46a83/src/StackExchange.Redis/ExceptionFactory.cs#L337